# "Досуг" и "досужий"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Досуг" и "досужий" (вымысел). Мне кажется, что эти слова связаны по смыслу. Досужий вымысел - это выдумка на досуге, в период безделья, пустого времяпрепровождения. А как считают коллеги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, связаны. Досужий вымысел — вымысел, сделанный на досуге, от нечего делать. То есть, не заслуживающий внимания.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что так и есть.